# Multiple Keys across the keyboard stop working at the same time

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure

First of all, I'm not sure if the question fits in here. If not please suggest a better place and I will move my question there.

About my problem: I have a gaming laptop and I often use the keyboard from the laptop. Now it happens that every 6-9 months the keyboard seems to be broken. It's an ongoing process. Some of the keys stop to work and I have to press them multiple times to get them back to work. This gets more worse over time until a point where I can reapetingly press these keys for up to 30 minutes and nothing happens.

The strange thing about this is that the keys are spread all across the keyboard and they stop working at the same time and they begin to work again at the same time. This time the keys that are not working are Q, 4, DEL, INS, 7 and 5 (both from numblock), F4 and F10.

So for example if the 'Q'-key isn't working the '7'-key from the numblock also isn't working. But if one of these starts to work again all the other affected keys also start to work again at the same time.

It's not a software issue as I can use these keys via the onscreen keyboard.

In the past I've send the notebook to the manufacturer and they just changed the keyboard and it works again for 6-9 months before the problem starts again but mostly with different keys. Currently it is the 5th keyboard in a little more than 3 years. The manufacturer also wasn't able to find the root cause and they said that I'm the only guy with this notebook who has such problems.

Soon I will have to send the notebook there again to replace the keyboard but the notebook is then away up to two weeks each time (~ 10 weeks in total up to now)

So my question is, has anyone of you heard of such problems or experienced them by himself? Any suggegtions what could be the root cause of this issue? I really appreciate any constructive help.

Just for information it is a membrane keyboard. (Not sure if it matters)